# C3p0 with Hibernate 4.2 error: setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V is abstract

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, configuration, c3p0

I am using Hibernate 4.2 with c3p0 and I am getting this error:`Method com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/NewProxyPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V is abstract`

Anybody knows which version should I use? Here is my current Maven dependencies list:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setCharacterStream%28int,%20java.io.Reader%29) method was added to JDBC 4 and according to C3P0 [release notes](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#basics):

> As of version 0.9.5, c3p0 fully supports the jdbc4 spec.

So you need to [update the C3p0 library to 0.9.5](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0/0.9.5):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

You might also exclude the C3P0 dependency from Hibernate, to make sure Maven uses the one you configured explicitly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Older versions of c3p0 can also slip in from other libraries. In our case it was Quartz 2.2.2

Comment: I actually have the updated libraries, but for some reason the logs keep saying "Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.1". I traced that actual string down to tika-app-1.10.jar, but I have no idea where to go from there...

Answer (score 1):

In my case after migration to hibernate 4 I had to add 
**c3p0-0.9.5.jar** and **mchange-commons-java-0.2.15.jar** (jar, becouse it is not maven project)

Comment: In my case also above worked (only difference it worked with 0.9.2) : 
JAR UPDATED to c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar , JAR ADDED = mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar

Answer (score 0):

use artifactId  c3p0   0.9.5.2    it's ok!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```