# Hibernate 4.3.11 with c3p0 0.9.5.2 setCharacterStream causes AbstractMethodError

Tags: spring, hibernate, c3p0

I know this issue has been treated in various question and in my opinion the answer in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399545/c3p0-with-hibernate-4-2-error-setcharacterstreamiljava-io-readerjv-is-abstra) seems like the logical solution, but for me it somehow doesn't help.
The error occurs when saving or updating only a certain entity. With all others it works strangely \oO/

Here's my stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1274)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:956)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$4$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:124)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:616)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1901)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at my.software..persistent.hibernate.dao.LanguageTextDaoHibernate.getLanguageKey(LanguageTextDaoHibernate.java:241)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.getLanguageKey(Unknown Source)
at my.software..util.language.LanguageTextUtil.getLanguageKey(LanguageTextUtil.java:125)
at my.software..propertysheet.TextProperties.setLanguageText(TextProperties.java:505)
at my.software..gui.dialog.spm.TextProducerDialog.buttonGetValues_actionPerformed(TextProducerDialog.java:296)
at my.software..gui.dialog.spm.TextProducerDialog.access$1(TextProducerDialog.java:279)
at my.software..gui.dialog.spm.TextProducerDialog$2.actionPerformed(TextProducerDialog.java:201)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at com.still.common.gui.dialog.DialogTemplate.createDialog(DialogTemplate.java:168)
at my.software..gui.dialog.spm.TextProducerDialog.init(TextProducerDialog.java:262)
at my.software..gui.dialog.spm.TextProducerDialog.<init>(TextProducerDialog.java:126)
at my.software..gui.action.spm.SpmTextAction.getActionNew(SpmTextAction.java:44)
at my.software..gui.toolbar.spm.SpmTextToolBar$3.actionPerformed(SpmTextToolBar.java:120)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

When I load the app the c3p0 log is:

```
INFO  [main] 07.04.17 14:37:17.389  com.mchange.v2.log.slf4j.Slf4jMLog$Slf4jMLogger$InfoLogger@log: Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
INFO  [main] 07.04.17 14:37:17.814  com.mchange.v2.log.slf4j.Slf4jMLog$Slf4jMLogger$InfoLogger@log: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 2wu2r69nk3dcuwd4fg5w|1a4bd3d, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 2wu2r69nk3dcuwd4fg5w|1a4bd3d, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 10, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://derlkim0425:1433/spm_dev_mirco, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 120, maxStatements -> 70, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
```

This is my pom.xml snippet (I had to exclude c3p0 from hibernate-c3p0 as it was loading older version that was not compatible with JDBC4 driver)

```
<!-- Hibernate Stuff -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    <!-- Hibernate Core needs a higher version so we exclude this one -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
                <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am clueless where to look for the root cause now...
Could this be related to some JPA config in the LanguageText Entity class ?
Nothing fancy in there though...

Thanks for any hints on this.

Comment: I just realized that it seems my Project is not using JDBC4 . It prints this log `INFO  [main] 07.04.17 15:19:11.978  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder@useContextualLobCreation: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4 ` . But Spring 4.3.11 should use JDBC4 ...now I'm even more confused

Comment: It has nothing to do with Spring nor C3P0... The driver you are using is a JDBC3 driver not a JDBC4 driver (which is also clearly stated at [the website](http://jtds.sourceforge.net)). Also you should remove the `hibernate-annotations` dependency as that should be included (or managed) by core already.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your reply. As the application I am working on is very old and took it over to refactor to newer technologies I have  a lot of work to do. Is there a way to go from JTDS to sth. with JDBC4 without any trouble ? I tried the original sqljdbc driver from microsoft, but then half of the HQL statements give me errors like `conversion from nvarchar to clob not possible` . Any Idea for a good approach here ? Why isn't there a successor of JTDS that uses JDBC4 ?

Comment: Why there isn't a JDBC4 version of JTDS you have to ask the project authors I cannot answer that. You did specify the correct dialect when switching to the other driver?

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't really expect an answer to my silly question ;-) I specified SQLServerDialect  and also tried with SQLServer2008

Comment: `nvarchar` maps to a `NCLOB` and not a `CLOB`... So that might be the issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum actually this mapping is happening somewhere in the driver, but not in my code. I don't know why it is chosing the wrong mapping vor nvarchar. In the table, there is a NVARCHAR field and with jtds this works without any issues. Maybe I have to configure the something regarding LOB creation ?

Comment: Well not in the driver but when converting back (or hibernate determine the actual underlying type). I suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found out what my issue was, and as usual it was sitting between chair and screen.
The setCharacterStream Method issue was resolved by adding a real JDBC4 driver. I chosed the one from Microsoft itself. 
I won't mention the ton of issues that came with this choice, but it solved the problem stated in the title.

For those who care:  My Problem with the conversion was really stupid. I had a closer look into the Entity Class and I found a @Lob annotation on a String field. Well...removing it, solved the issue of conversion. I have no clue why this worked with JTDS (i assume JTDS is more clever than the MS driver and has some internal auto conversion for such cases...) .